# export HTML to DOCX with Docx4j

Tags: docx4j

I need to generate a DOCX from Webpage (with Images). Will it be possible for DOCX4J to export the HTML Content to DOCX Format ?

Are there any other libraries which can export HTML Content to DOCX?

Answer (score 0):

The **docx4j-ImportXHTML** project does what you want.

See the [sample code](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/tree/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples).