# How to fix: DOCX to HTML with DOCX4J error (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, spring, xhtml, docx, docx4j

I am trying to convert DOCX to HTML using DOCX4j, Java 11, Spring boot 2.3.5, Ubuntu 18.04.5, and I am running my .WAR file on tomcat 9.

When I run the code, I get this error. How can I fix this?

My Code

references:

1. [export HTML to DOCX with Docx4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762101/export-html-to-docx-with-docx4j?rq=1)
2. https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/DocxToXhtmlAndBack.java

   ```
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(source));

    HTMLSettings htmlSettings = Docx4J.createHTMLSettings();
    htmlSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);
    htmlSettings.setImageDirPath("temp_images");
    htmlSettings.setImageTargetUri("temp_images");
    htmlSettings.setImageIncludeUUID(false);

    boolean nestLists = false;
    if (nestLists) {
        SdtWriter.registerTagHandler("HTML_ELEMENT", new SdtToListSdtTagHandler());
    } else {
        // convert numberings to plain text
        htmlSettings.getFeatures().remove(ConversionFeatures.PP_HTML_COLLECT_LISTS);
    } 

    OutputStream os = new java.io.FileOutputStream(dest);
    Docx4J.toHTML(htmlSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
   ```

Pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.5</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.docx.xwpf</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Log file:

```
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception exporting package
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception exporting package
        at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:106)
        at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toHTML(Docx4J.java:830)
        at com.home.converter.Xhtmlconv.startConveter(Xhtmlconv.java:141)
        at com.home.controller.myproject.shephard.GetController.getStartGenerateXhtml(GetController.java:1377)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.ObfuscatedFontPart.deleteEmbeddedFontTempFiles(ObfuscatedFontPart.java:263)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.FontTablePart.deleteEmbeddedFontTempFiles(FontTablePart.java:161)
        at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:90)
        ... 61 more
```

Edit:
I tried to run he same WAR on tomcat 9, Windows 10 and everything is working. Interesting... But how can I fix this problem on linux-tomcat? (Checked the tomcat / linux, those are okay and NOT corrupted)

Comment: Please try a newer docx4j, for example, 8.2.4.

Comment: I removed <dependency><groupId>org.docx4j</groupId><artifactId>docx4j</artifactId><version>6.1.2</version> </dependency> and changed docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl version to 8.2.4, 8.2.6, 11.2.5. but unfortunately, I get the same nullpointerexception. As a reference, I used this: https://www.docx4java.org/downloads.html

Comment: The NPE should at least be at a different line number.

Comment: So please advise that, using 8.2.6

Comment: You are right, NEP is at a different line number:
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.ObfuscatedFontPart.deleteEmbeddedFontTempFiles(ObfuscatedFontPart.java:202)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.FontTablePart.deleteEmbeddedFontTempFiles(FontTablePart.java:176)
at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:90)

Comment: Looks like your tmpFontDir is null.  https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/AbstractFontPart.java#L66 is what sets it.  consider setting property 'docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.ObfuscatedFontPart.tmpFontDir'?

Comment: I will try it, but what should be the value of this property? I set to "/usr/share/fonts" but didn't work.

Comment: Try TOMCAT_HOME/temp (substituting the actual path in there)

Comment: That's the solution! :) Thank you, if you put it as an answer, I will accept it. I would like to ask 1 more question, if you don't mind. can you help me with this one too? Thank you and have a nice day! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65251150/docx-to-html-headings-font-style-is-not-correct-using-docx4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your tmpFontDir is null.

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/AbstractFontPart.java#L66 is what sets it.

Consider setting property `docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.ObfuscatedFontPart.tmpFontDir`

Since you are using Tomcat, set it toTOMCAT_HOME/temp (substituting the actual path in there).