# Docx to HTML: Headings' font style is not correct using DOCX4J

Tags: java, html, docx, docx4j

I have a docx file with Heading1 style with Calibri Light (every other texts use Calibri Light too). After converting to html, Every texts are Calibri Light (correctly), but the text with Heading1 style is Times New Roman when I open the html file. (The reason: there is no font-family set for Heading1 style, inside of html file)

When I open the docx file and check the Heading1 style's font, it says Calibri Light.

Heading1 is based on "Normal" style in docx.

This is the Normal style in docx:

```
<w:style w:type="paragraph"
        w:default="1"
        w:styleId="Normal">
    <w:name w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:qFormat/>
    <w:rsid w:val="003D736F"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:before="40"
                    w:after="40"
                    w:line="240"
                    w:lineRule="auto"/>
        <w:ind w:left="851"/>
        <w:jc w:val="both"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri Light"
                    w:eastAsia="SimSun"
                    w:hAnsi="Calibri Light"
                    w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        <w:shd w:val="clear"
                w:color="auto"
                w:fill="FFFFFF"/>
        <w:lang w:eastAsia="zh-CN"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:style>
```

I can see, we have 4 fonts. But can we tell DOCX4J, to use a specific font (like, use w:ascii and put this font to the Heading1 style in html file?) Heading1 styled texts should be Calibri Light too, this is my goal.

And this is the Heading1 style:

```
    <w:style w:type="paragraph"
            w:styleId="Heading1">
        <w:name w:val="heading 1"/>
        <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
        <w:next w:val="Normal"/>
        <w:link w:val="Heading1Char"/>
        <w:qFormat/>
        <w:rsid w:val="00232342"/>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:keepNext/>
            <w:keepLines/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:numId w:val="4"/>
            </w:numPr>
            <w:spacing w:before="360"
                        w:after="240"/>
            <w:jc w:val="left"/>
            <w:outlineLvl w:val="0"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:b/>
            <w:sz w:val="32"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:style>
```

This is the code I am using:

```
 WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(source));

 HTMLSettings htmlSettings = Docx4J.createHTMLSettings();
 htmlSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);
 htmlSettings.setImageDirPath("temp_images");
 htmlSettings.setImageTargetUri("temp_images");
 htmlSettings.setImageIncludeUUID(false);

 boolean nestLists = false;
 if (nestLists) {
     SdtWriter.registerTagHandler("HTML_ELEMENT", new SdtToListSdtTagHandler());
 } else {
     // convert numberings to plain text
     htmlSettings.getFeatures().remove(ConversionFeatures.PP_HTML_COLLECT_LISTS);
 } 

 OutputStream os = new java.io.FileOutputStream(dest);
 Docx4J.toHTML(htmlSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
```

And this is the 2 styles in html

```
.Normal {display:block;text-align: justify;position: relative; margin-left: 15mm;margin-top: 1mm;margin-bottom: 1mm;line-height: 100%;}

.Heading1 {display:block;text-align: left;page-break-after: avoid;margin-top: 0.25in;margin-bottom: 4mm;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16.0pt;}
```

Edit:
Other acceptable solution can be this: set a font-family to "DocDefaults" style in html file. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you put somewhere a simple sample docx which exhibits the issue?

Comment: Yes. This example has an extra problem: after the convering, we can see multiple black rows in the title page (i don't know why)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/163eq0LOGjFFxAIkiTgCT9qHqfliUMBSg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Font-family is handled using directly applied CSS.

For example:

```
  <li class="Heading1 Normal DocDefaults " style="display: list-item;"><span class="DefaultParagraphFont " style="font-family: 'Calibri Light';">Chapter 2</span></li></ol>
  
  <p class="Normal DocDefaults "><span class="" style="font-family: 'Calibri Light';">This is an example part, chapter 2</span></p></div>
```

For font-family to be applied, the font must either be physically present on your machine, or mapped to a font which is physically present (see docx4j's ConvertOutHtml sample for an example).

If this is not the case, no font-family property will be emitted.

For greater insight, you can turn debug level logging on for  org.docx4j.fonts.RunFontSelector.  Example logging:

```
08:54:21.295 [main] DEBUG org.docx4j.fonts.RunFontSelector 1136 - looking for: Calibri Light
08:54:21.295 [main] DEBUG org.docx4j.fonts.RunFontSelector 1144 - Font 'Calibri Light' maps to Calibri Light
```

Comment: My debug:

 WARN 1569 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts           : Overwriting existing physicalFontMap entry: calibri light
WARN 1569 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts           : Overwriting existing physicalFontMap entry: calibri
WARN 1569 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.docx4j.fonts.Mapper                  : Overwriting existing fontMapping: calibri light
WARN 1569 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.docx4j.fonts.Mapper                  : Overwriting existing fontMapping: calibri

Comment: The problem still exists: everything is calibri light, except the the 2 numbers of the Heading1. ('1.' and '2.') Everything else is okay (tried to use `PhysicalFonts.discoverPhysicalFonts(); ` but didn't solve my problem)

Comment: You don't need to do that.  So, is Calibri installed on your machine or not?  Are you setting a FontMapper, for example:   Mapper fontMapper = new IdentityPlusMapper(); wordMLPackage.setFontMapper(fontMapper);

Comment: Well, it was not installed on my linux. What I did is just copy-pasted the calibri TTF file to /USR/SHARE/FONTS/TRUETYPE

And no, i am not setting FontMapper. Is it recommended to do that?